# How to prevent "blur" event on input field?

Tags: javascript, onblur, onfocus

I have a form with two input fields **user** and **pass**. When the user leaves an empty username field it should be refocused (the blur event should be prevented).

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("user");

userInput.addEventListener("focus", function(ev) {
  console.log("user.focus");
});

userInput.addEventListener("blur", function(ev) {
  console.log("user.blur");
  if (userInput.value == "") {
    console.log("user.refocus");
    userInput.focus();
  }
});

var passInput = document.getElementById("pass");

passInput.addEventListener("focus", function(ev) {
  console.log("pass.focus");
});

passInput.addEventListener("blur", function(ev) {
  console.log("pass.blur");
});
```

```html
user: <input id="user" /> pass: <input id="pass" />
```

The code above is working in the following browsers:

- Google Chrome
- MS Edge
- WebKit GTK (don't laugh)

But not in these:

- Internet Explorer
- Firefox

Any idea on how this can be solved cross-browser?

Comment: this seems to be a bad ux - let the user do what they want

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for your input. This is just a simplified version of the real application in which the problem must be solved this way.

Comment: Try calling `ev.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that already. It unfortunately makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to pretend to explain why this doesn't work in some browsers but using a really short `setTimeout()` for the refocusing allows it to work in Firefox at least.

My reasoning for trying this approach was to let the original blur event complete before focusing again

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("user");

userInput.addEventListener("focus", function(ev) {
  console.log("user.focus");
});

userInput.addEventListener("blur", function(ev) {
  console.log("user.blur");
  if (userInput.value == "") {
    console.log("user.refocus");
    setTimeout(()=>{
       userInput.focus();
    },50)
  }
});

var passInput = document.getElementById("pass");

passInput.addEventListener("focus", function(ev) {
  console.log("pass.focus");
});

passInput.addEventListener("blur", function(ev) {
  console.log("pass.blur");
});
```

```html
user: <input id="user" /> pass: <input id="pass" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the "focus" and "blur" event handlers of the other field get executed this way, which is something that mustn't happen, because in the application that field might also have the same logic and this would create an endless loop in which the browser is jumping between the two fields.

Comment: Well none of that was mentioned in question. I agree with one of the initial comments that this is strange and perhaps it is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well, yes it's strange, but it's a client requirement. We already found a workaround, but I was curious if anybody knows a better way of handling this.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to completely prevent user from blurring away from an input